# How to edit GroupBox Lines?

Tags: nsis

I want to know if is possible to change the width or depth of feeling of a GroupBox lines created with NSIS Dialog Designer.
I have reviewed the options provided NSIS Dialog Designer and have not found anything I can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it covers some style altering functions: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=297157